# Removing whitespace from strings in Groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I have a string like

```
String  str = "My name is Monda"
```

How can I achieve a string like

```
str  = "MynameisMonda"
```

Answer (score 65):

You can use the [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#replaceAll(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) function.

For your case:

```
replaceAll("\\s","")
```

where `\s` means any whitespace (such as a space character).

Comment: If you use this line breaks will be removed as well. In my case this behavior triggered errors further down the groovy script

Answer (score 40):

You just need this function. `replaceAll()`

```
str.replaceAll("\\s","")
```

`\s` = Anything that is a space character (including space, tab characters etc)

You need to escape the backslash if you want \s to reach the regex engine, resulting in \s. Like wise we use :-

`\S` = Anything that isn't a space character (including both letters and numbers, as well as punctuation etc)

`\w` = Anything that is a word character

`\W` = Anything that isn't a word character (including punctuation etc)